# Input String was not in a correct format (c# simple method)

Tags: c#, winforms

I know there are lots of threads on this matter but I couldn't find a solution that worked. I'm very new to c# so i'm not entirely sure what to do. Basically this method is that when a user enters a value into the textWithdraw.text textfield, they will either be issued with an error for entering a letter etc or they will be shown a message displaying the amount they are to withdraw. I'm still working on the method to make it more efficient.
txtBalance.text is the users existing balance incase anyone was wondering what its for.
This is the bit of code where I'm getting the error.

```
error= double numberEntered = double.Parse(txtWithdraw.Text);
whole method
private void newBalance()
    {
        double numberEntered = double.Parse(txtWithdraw.Text);
        double balance = double.Parse(txtBalance.Text);
      double newBalance = balance - numberEntered;
        txtBalance.Text=((balance - numberEntered).ToString());

      if (numberEntered < 1 || numberEntered > 9999999)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a number between 1 and 10");
        }

        else
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(numberEntered.ToString()), "You have withdrawn");
        txtWithdraw.Text = "";
        // MessageBox.Show(newBalance.ToString(),numberEntered.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Either txtWithdraw or txtBalance contains text which cannot be parsed to double number

Comment: Note that `double.Parse` expects the number to be in the user's culture by default. So if you're in a country that needs a decimal comma instead of a dot you need to follow that (it doesn't mimic C#'s format for `double` literals).

Comment: You probably want to add some kind of input validation, try/catch, or use `TryParse`.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, it would be better to use a control which better matches your data.  In this case, a [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control may be better, because it already has logic for min/max values, which prevents users from inputting invalid numbers rather than raising message boxes.  Additionally, it uses a decimal type, which is better for financial operations, as it does not suffer from floating-point errors.

Comment: what you mean by "I'm still working on the method to make it more efficient"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check if string can be parsed to double. This method returns boolean value instead of throwing exception. Check this value and notify user if data in wrong format:

```
private void newBalance()
{      
    double withdraw;
    if (!double.TryParse(txtWithdraw.Text, out withdraw));
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please, enter correct withdraw number");
        return;
    }

    if (withdraw < 1 || 9999999 < withdraw)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a number between 1 and 10");
        return;
    }

    double balance;
    if (!double.TryParse(txtBalance.Text, out balance));
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please, enter correct balance number");
        return;
    }

    balance -= withdraw;
    txtBalance.Text = balance.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(withdraw.ToString()), "You have withdrawn");
    txtWithdraw.Text = "";
}
```

I also suggest you to handle `Validating` event of textboxes to check if value in correct format just after it was entered. See [User Input Validation in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Or use `NumericUpDown` control to avoid non-numeric input.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Double.TryParse()` function to check wether the given input can be converted into double or not.

From MSDN:[Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style
>   and culture-specific format to its double-precision floating-point
>   number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded or failed.

Try This:

```
private void newBalance()
{
   double numberEntered ;
   double balance ; 
   if(double.TryParse(txtWithdraw.Text,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.None,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out numberEntered))
   {
     if(double.TryParse(txtBalance.Text,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.None,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out balance))
     {
        double newBalance = balance - numberEntered;
        txtBalance.Text=((balance - numberEntered).ToString());

        if (numberEntered < 1 || numberEntered > 9999999)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a number between 1 and 10");
        }

        else
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format(numberEntered.ToString()), "You have withdrawn");
        txtWithdraw.Text = "";
        // MessageBox.Show(newBalance.ToString(),numberEntered.ToString());
     }
   }
}
```